# How to style a JList

Tags: java, swing, border, jlist, margins

Is there a way to style a JList in the following ways:

1. Set the Border to a custom color, or even remove it completely
2. Set custom margins between the JList edges and the content displayed
3. Set custom margins between the rows of text

Feel free to post any ideas I can try out on a JList, even those you may know of I've not listed above.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html

Answer (score 4):

"Styling" is the domain of the UI delegate and cell renderer.

In every day working, the cell renderer is, by far, the simpler choice.  This will allow you to modify the look of the rows and format the content as you see fit.

Take a look at [How to use Lists](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html), in particular, [Writing a custom cell renderer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html#renderer) for examples

If you don't mind a little more more work, you can also take a look at [The Synth Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/synth.html) which is a type of skinning API ontop of the look and feel API